# SELinux has denied sendmail access to potentially mislabeled file(s)

Tags: centos, selinux

Has everyone every recieved this SELinux error?

> SELinux has denied sendmail access to
>   potentially mislabeled file(s)
>   (2F746D702F746D70664A6163564B62202864656C6574656429)

What is with that file name? I have been receiving these in my emails constantly lately and I have no idea where that file is coming from.

Thanks for any help!
Metropolis

Answer (score 1):

> This means that SELinux will not allow
>   sendmail to use these files. It is
>   common for users to edit files in
>   their home directory or tmp
>   directories and then move (mv) them to
>   system directories. The problem is
>   that the files end up with the wrong
>   file context which confined
>   applications are not allowed to
>   access.
>
> Allowing Access:
>
> If you want sendmail to access this
>   files, you need to relabel them using

```
restorecon -v '2F746D702F746D70664A6163564B62202864656C6574656429'.
```

> You might want to relabel the entire
>   directory using

```
restorecon -R -v ''
```

http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2008-03/msg01150.html

---

Dan Walsh on that same mailing list - who is one of "the man" on SELinux suggests the following:

> These avc's show sendmail attempting
>   to read files created by the apache
>   process (mod_php) in /tmp. sendmail is
>   also trying to read a file off of
>   /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat which is
>   labeled usr_t. The easiest thing for
>   you to do is to build a local policy
>   module

```
grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M myhttp
semodule -i myhttp.pp
```

You would need audit2allow for this (may already be installed).

It may be helpful to share your avcs you get. (should be logged to /var/log/message)

Comment: Whenever I try restorecon -v '2F746D702F746D70664A6163564B62202864656C6574656429', I get the error "No such file or directory" which is what I have been running into while trying to run that.